# Python - How to append conditionaly in array?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (records). Each record consists of 4 elements: `[id, msg_key, msg_value, date]`

For example:

```
events = [
    [1, "foo", "bar",  709],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 710],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  711],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 712],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  713],
    [2, "foo", "toto", 714],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  715],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 716]
]
```

I want to build a filtered version of this list of records with the following criteria.

> Given the current record ensure that the last prior record with the
> same `id` and `msg_key` as the current record, does not have the same
> `msg_value`.

In this case:

```
events = [
    [1, "foo", "bar",  709],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 710],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  711],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 712],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  713], # <-----------------------------------------------┐
    [2, "foo", "toto", 714], #                                                 |
    [1, "foo", "bar",  715], # remove as same "msg_value" as "matching" row ---┘
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 716]
]
```

So the end result I seek is:

```
events_filtered = [
    [1, "foo", "bar",  709],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 710],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  711],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 712],
    [1, "foo", "bar",  713],
    [2, "foo", "toto", 714],
    [1, "foo", "bar2", 716]
]
```

I have tried to filter out that row but I can't figure out the correct steps.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```py
    out_array = []
    for ... :
        event = [id, msg_key, msg_value, date]
        if ?????:
            out_array.append(event)
```

Comment: I have read the question multiple times, I still don't understand it. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: what do you mean by _But in my case I want check if previous date exist have same id, msg_key, msg_value_
Do you mean to only check if the prev element has the same properties not including the date?

Comment: Can you rewrite the question in understandable English? It is difficult to understand. Also, the example is not comprehensive.

Comment: @nokla, yes you understand

Comment: Why is the row that ends with `...15` excluded but not the row that ends with `...09`?

Comment: @KellyBundy, there are no duplicates that follow each other

Comment: JonSG, 1696515709 is the 1st

Comment: @KellyBundy, id=1 and msg_key=foo exist but msg_value=`bar` and previous of id=1 and msg_key=foo is with msg_value=`bar2`

Comment: Please take a look as see if you agree that my edit is what you seek to do.

Comment: FYI, in Python we call this a list, not an array. Arrays are found in the `numpy` and `xarray` libraries, they're different.

Comment: @JonSG, yes is exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply keep the previous value (per key: `id`, `msg_key`)  in a `dict`, so you would just need to lookup that key:

```
events = ([1, "foo", "bar", 1696515709], [1, "foo", "bar2", 1696515710],
          [1, "foo", "bar",
           1696515711], [1, "foo", "bar2",
                         1696515712], [1, "foo", "bar", 1696515713],
          [2, "foo", "toto",
           1696515714], [1, "foo", "bar",
                         1696515715], [1, "foo", "bar2", 1696515716])

prev_items = {}
out_array = []
for (id, msg_key, msg_value, date) in events:
    key = (id, msg_key)
    if prev_items.get(key, None) != msg_value:
        out_array.append([id, msg_key, msg_value, date])
    prev_items[key] = msg_value

expected_out = [[1, "foo", "bar", 1696515709], [1, "foo", "bar2", 1696515710],
                [1, "foo", "bar", 1696515711], [1, "foo", "bar2", 1696515712],
                [1, "foo", "bar", 1696515713], [2, "foo", "toto", 1696515714],
                [1, "foo", "bar2", 1696515716]]

print(expected_out == out_array)
```

Out:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to remove duplicates (same data with different id assigned.) form list. If this is the case then below code using for-else may help:

```
def fd(t1):
    oa=[] # cleaned data
    did=[] # duplicate id list
    for i in t1:
        for j in oa:
            if i[1:] == j[1:]: # if keys are same then id was duplicated
                did.append((i[0],j[0])) 
                break
        else: # no break entry is unique
            oa.append(i)
    return oa, did
```

sample result:

```
>> t1
[[2, ' foo', ' toto', 1696515714], [1, ' foo', ' bar', 1696515715], [8, ' foo', ' bar2', 1696515716], [9, ' foo', ' bar2', 1696515716]]
>>> fd(t1)
([[2, ' foo', ' toto', 1696515714], [1, ' foo', ' bar', 1696515715], [8, ' foo', ' bar2', 1696515716]], [(9, 8)])
```